# changing multiple columns of a matrix with respect to sorted indices of its specific columns

Tags: matlab, sorting

Let's say I have a 2 by 9 matrix. I want to replace the 2 by 3 matrices inside this matrix with respect to descending sort of `a(2,3)`, `a(2,6)`, and `a(2,9)` elements. For example:

```
a =

    0.4    0.4   0.5   0.6   0.2  0.2  0.6  0.2  0.6
    0.5    0.8   0.9   0.9   0.6  0.6  0.1  0.2  0.8

[b i] = sort(a(2,3:3:end),2,'descend')

b =

    0.9    0.8    0.6


i =

     1     3     2
```

So, I want to have the following matrix:

```
a = 

0.4  0.4  0.5  0.6  0.2  0.6  0.6  0.2  0.6

0.5  0.8  0.9  0.1  0.2  0.8  0.9  0.6  0.6
```

Comment: You mean *2*-by-*9* right?

Answer (score 4):

Try converting to a cell matrix first and then using your `i` to rearrange the cells

```
[b i] = sort(a(2,3:3:end),2,'descend')

A = mat2cell(a, 2, 3*ones(1,3));
cell2mat(A(i))
```

If for whatever reason you don't want to convert the whole of `a` into a cell matrix, you can do it by extending your indexing vector `i` to index all the columns. In your case you'd need:

```
I = [1,2,3,7,8,9,4,5,6]
```

which you could generate using a loop or else use `bsxfun` to get

```
[1  7  4
 2  8  5
 3  9  6]
```

and then "flatten" using `reshape`:

```
I = reshape(bsxfun(@plus, 3*s-2, (0:2)'), 1, [])
```

and then finally

```
a(:,I)
```

Comment: It works but is there another way of doing this without converting to a cell matrix

Comment: @kenes why not use the cell array method? But yes you can do without it, see my edit

Comment: I noticed later that you changed the cell to matrix again. Sorry.

Answer (score 1):

Typically, when a 2d matrix is separated into blocks, best practice ist to use more dimensions:

```
a=reshape(a,size(a,1),3,[]);
```

Now you can access each block via `a(:,:,1)`
To sort use:

```
[~,idx]=sort(a(2,3,:),'descend')
a=a(:,:,idx)
```

If you really need a 2d matrix, change back:

```
a=reshape(a,2,[])
```

Answer (score 0):

[`sortrows`](http://es.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/sortrows.html)-based approach:

```
n = 3; %// number of columns per block
m = size(a,1);
a = reshape(sortrows(reshape(a, m*n, []).', -m*n).', m, []);
```

This works by reshaping each block into a row, sorting rows according to last column, and reshaping back.